Передача графического файла с одной страницы на другую одного и того же сайта
На одной странице сайта размещаю изображение с кнопкой "Использовать". Вопрос: можно ли, и если возможно, то как - при клике на эту кнопку открыть другую страницу сайта с уже имеющейся на ней формой с input type="file" и "вставить" это изображение (файл) в этот input? Вообще, в идеале, с превью...
Спасибо.

Тоесть, с странички А на которой есть картинка, нужно открыть страницу Б, которые вообще никак не связаны, при этом передав на эту страницу в форму данные из страницы А, верно?.. можно, просто отправив нужный POST по нужному адресу) что касается с превью.. JS такое тоже позволяет, если запрос будет дублирован, какая разница куда загружать.. если я вообще вас правильно понял

Да, все верно вы поняли! То есть, на странице А имеется изображение (допустим, файл лежит в директории /images). Ну и при клике на кнопку нужно перейти на страницу Б, где уже размещена форма с input file и вставить в него этот файлик. Желательно, конечно, с превьюшкой. Как я вас понял - сделать это можно, спасибо! Только вот пример кода никак не могу "накопать"... ((

Это не позволит сделать безопасность браузера, иначе браузеры могли скриптами без вашего ведома скачивать с директорий файлы, т.е. с  можно работать только через их интерфейс для заполнения выбранных файлов.

А в чем вообще смысл передавать на сервер картинку, которая и так там есть? Если надо обработать конкретную картинку, то и передавайте её имя.
